# No such module 'Cocoa' in Swift Playground

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I'm trying to follow some of the code used in the WWDC playgrounds session, I'm trying to import the Cocoa framework with:

```
import Cocoa
```

But I get the following error in the assistant editor

```
Playground execution failed: error: <REPL>:3:8: error: no such module 'Cocoa'
```

I'm at 41:20 in the video if that helps at all.

Comment: you should be able to...restart xcode?

Comment: @connor yeah, I tried that first as restarting has fixed similar issue in the past. No such luck this time.

Comment: Try to create a new playground

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You are using an iOS playground (UIKit-based), not an OS X playground (Cocoa-based). Try creating a new playground and choosing "OS X" as the type instead of "iOS". It should work fine after that.

You can also change the type for an existing playground in the File Inspector (View→Inspectors→Show File Inspector) under Playground Settings→Platform.

By default, new iOS playgrounds are created with boilerplate including `import UIKit`; OS X playgrounds are created with boilerplate including `import Cocoa`, so if you find yourself manually typing "`import Cocoa`", it's probably a clue you've got the wrong type.

Comment: How do I get "OS X playground" to be an option? The only option I see is "iOS"? I have X-Code 6.01

Comment: @jeff_kile For OS X Swift development, you'll need Xcode 6.1, *not* 6.0.1. See [this Apple Swift Blog entry](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=14) for details—basically for OS X, Swift is still beta, not GM, so you'll need to download the current Xcode *beta* from the Dev Center for OS X support.

Comment: worked for me!!

Answer (score 16):

If you are getting this or a similar type of error despite having the playground set properly, try the following:

Close XCode and from the terminal run:

```
 rm -rf "$(getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR)/org.llvm.clang/ModuleCache"
```

Then reopen XCode and most times this fixes many Playground issues.  I run this command quite frequently during an intensive Playground work session (sometimes as many as a few times per hour) and have found liberal use of removing the ModuleCache to solve a multitude of strange playground behaviors.

If you're still having issues with playgrounds you can try:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```

and/or

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode
```

Comment: In Xcode 7, my clang module cache was actually at `org.llvm.clang.<user>` instead. So this command worked for me: `rm -rf "$(getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR)org.llvm.clang.$USER/ModuleCache"`

Answer (score 1):

This answer helped me:

https://forums.bignerdranch.com/t/import-cocoa-in-playground-is-giving-error/8091/2

> I fixed it… never replace an iOS playground by a OS X playground when you name them the 
>       same…
>       it’ll stick with the iOS mode…

Comment: Thank-you! That worked for my situation.