# how to add background music

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

The **duplicate** answer does not *works* at all

```
import Cocoa
    import AVFoundation

    var error: NSError?

    println("Hello, Audio!")
    var url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/somebody/myfile.mid") // Change to a local midi file
    var midi = AVMIDIPlayer(contentsOfURL: url, soundBankURL: nil, error: &error)
    if midi == nil {
        if let e = error {
            println("AVMIDIPlayer failed: " + e.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    midi.play(nil)
    while midi.playing {
        // Spin (yeah, that's bad!)
    }
```

[image: Hello Audio]
[image: The operation couldn't be completed]

Comment: The `Cocoa` framework is used when you are developing macOS apps and does not exist on the iOS platform, that is why you are seeing that error :) To fix it, try replacing `import Cocoa` with `import UIKit` for instance. See this answer too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24099668/4063602 Hope that helps

Comment: @pbodsk   Even after replacing import Cocoa with import UIKit it is not **working**

Comment: OK. The first one is easy. Instead of `println()` you just write `print()`, so `print("Hello, Audio!")` for instance. As for the `AVMIDIPlayer` error. Are you still importing `AVFoundation`? You need to import _both_ `UIKit` _and_ `AVFoundation`.

Comment: @pbodsk Yes i am importing both **UIKit as well as AVFoundation**

Comment: @pbodsk even after adding a new link it is not working

Comment: And by new link you mean a new URL I guess? And also...not working..how :) Do you see an error in the console somewhere that could help us?

Comment: @pbodsk import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

print("Hello, Audio!")
var url = URL(fileURLWithPath:"file:///Users/paulfamilymachine/Desktop/nyan-cat-tune%202.mp3") // Change to a local midi file
do {
    let midi = try AVMIDIPlayer(contentsOf: url, soundBankURL: nil)
    midi.play(nil)
    while midi.isPlaying {
        // Spin (yeah, that's bad!)
    }
} catch (let error) {
    print("AVMIDIPlayer failed: " + error.localizedDescription)
}

Comment: @pbodsk it says Hello, Audio!
AVMIDIPlayer failed: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio error -1.) at the bottom but it does not shows any error  URL of the screenshot [link](file:///Users/paulfamilymachine/Desktop/Screen%20Shot%202017-03-30%20at%201.41.40%20PM.png)

Comment: I'm guessing now, but maybe you can not reference a fileURL on your computer directly in your playground when you are running as an iOS playground. Try seeing if this answer helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31500936/4063602

Comment: @pbodsk It shows error it says (use of unresolved identifier 'Bundle')

Comment: @pbodsk after adding the item in the resource folder i don't think it should be inserted in a URL form [Link]

Comment: @pbodsk https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfyCG.png

Comment: @pbodsk  in Both of the cases no audio is coming By directly applying the same code it show no **error** (https://i.stack.imgur.com/w22tO.png) but when changing the file format to **.midi** to starts giving error (https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwQYw.png)

Comment: Image1 (trying to play "drum01"): I'm guessing you don't have a file named drum01.mp3 in your playground? Since you don't have that, the URL will not be created (it is an optional) and we won't try to play anything at all. Therefore no error. Image 2 (trying to play "nyan-cat-tune 2.midi"). Do you have a midi file in your playground? Not just a file renamed from nyan-cat-tune 2.mp3 to nyan-cat-tune 2.midi but an _actual_ midi file? Because the error code complains that you are trying to serve something to it that it cannot read

Comment: @pbodsk the background music is running perfectly but due to the music my main programme is not executing

Comment: OK. Well, I don't have anything more to contribute, sorry. If you feel that my answer has helped you, feel free to up vote it or mark it as the right answer. Perhaps you should ask another question with your new problem, I mean, you seem to have progressed from were you where when this question was asked.

Comment: @pbodsk Do you have any idea why it is happening?

Answer (score 1):

I've made a couple of changes to your code but this seems to "work" (we'll get to that)

First off, import the MP3 file to your playground as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31500936/4063602)

Then you can use your file like so:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

print("Hello, Audio!")
if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "drum01", withExtension: "mp3") {
    do {
        let midi = try AVMIDIPlayer(contentsOf: url, soundBankURL: nil)
        midi.play(nil)
        while midi.isPlaying {
            // Spin (yeah, that's bad!)
        }
    } catch (let error) {
        print("AVMIDIPlayer failed: " + error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Notice:

- `print`instead of `println`
- In Swift 3 a lot of things was renamed and some of the "old" methods that took an `&error` parameter was changed to use `do try catch` instead. Therefore the `error` has gone from your call and has been replaced with a `try`.
- **The above will fail!** You will see error code -10870 which can be found in the `AUComponent.h` header file and which translates to:

> kAudioUnitErr_UnknownFileType
>
> If an audio unit uses external files as a data source, this error is returned
>
> if a file is invalid (Apple's DLS synth returns this error)

So...this leads me to thinking you need to do one of two things, either:

1. find a .midi file and use that with the `AVMidiPlayer`
2. find something else to play your file, for instance `AVFilePlayer` or `AVAudioEngine`

(you can read more about error handling in Swift [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH42-ID508)).

Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

The mp3 file must be in the Resources folder.

You play an mp3 with code like this (not the MIDI player):

```
if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "drum01", withExtension: "mp3") {
  let player = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
  player?.prepareToPlay()
  player?.play()
}
```